# push notification show incorrect time kotlin, sometimes not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
    i want to show push notification in kotlin at 7 AM & 16PM in here every 24Hours everyday. i make 2 broadcast receiver & 2 declare time inside oncreate, but sometimes push notification not show, i dont know if receiver blocked by miui saver
    
    below my code AlarmBroadcastreceiver (for show 7 AM):
    
    class AlarmBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            showNotification(context)
    
        }
    
    
        internal fun showNotification(context: Context) {
            val CHANNEL_ID = "1"// The id of the channel.
            val name = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)// The user-visible name of the channel.
            val mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
    
            val intent = Intent()
            val manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
            when(manufacturer) {
                "xiaomi" ->
                    intent.component =
                        ComponentName(
                            "com.miui.securitycenter",
                            "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"
                        )
                "oppo" ->
                    intent.component =
                        ComponentName(
                            "com.coloros.safecenter",
                            "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"
                        )
                "vivo" ->
                    intent.component =
                        ComponentName(
                            "com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                            "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"
                        )
                "samsung" ->
                    intent.component =
                        ComponentName(
                            "com.samsung.android.lool",
                            "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"
                        )
    
                "asus" ->
                    intent.component =
                        ComponentName(
                            "com.asus.mobilemanager",
                            "com.asus.mobilemanager.MainActivity"
                        )
            }
    
            val list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
            )
            if (list.size > 0) {
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
    
    
            val notificationIntent = Intent(context, GreenHCMActivity::class.java)
            val bundle = Bundle()
            notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle)
    
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    
            //val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
              //  context,
                //1,
                //notificationIntent,
                //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            //)
    
            var contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                1,
                notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
            val mNotificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            //mNotificationManager.cancel(1)
           // mNotificationManager.cancelAll()
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
            {
    
                val mChannel = NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    name,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    
    
                )
    
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
    
                mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLights(Color.RED, 300, 300)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                     .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    // Overrides ContentTitle in the big form of the template.
                    .setContentTitle("Selamat Pagi Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi ")
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    
                    //.setContentTitle("Selamat Pagi Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi ")
    
    
            }
    
    
            else
            {
                mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    //.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    
                    //lollipop, marshmallow, nougat
                    .setContentTitle("Selamat Pagi Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi ")
                    .setStyle(
                        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
    
                            // Provide the bitmap to be used as the payload for the BigPicture notification.
                            .bigPicture(
                                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                    context.resources,
                                    R.drawable.absence
                                )
                            )
    
    
                            .setSummaryText("Mohon melakukan absensi pagi ini,Terima kasih")
                            // Override the large icon when the big notification is shown.
                            .bigLargeIcon(
                                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                    context.resources,
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round
                                )
                            )
                    )
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
            }
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            val note = mBuilder.build()
           mBuilder.setContentText("Mohon melakukan absensi pagi ini,Terima kasih")
    
    
               .setStyle(
                   NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
    
                       // Provide the bitmap to be used as the payload for the BigPicture notification.
                       .bigPicture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.absence))
    
                       // Override the large icon when the big notification is shown.
                       .bigLargeIcon(
                           BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                               context.resources,
                               R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round
                           )
                       )
    
    
                   // Set the first line of text after the detail section in the big form of the template.
                   //.setSummaryText("Mohon melakukan absensi pagi ini,Terima kasih")
    
               )
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build())
    
    
    
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    }


below my code Alarmbroadcastreceiver2 for show 16PM :

class AlarmBroadcastReceiver2: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        showNotification(context)

    }
    internal fun showNotification(context: Context) {
        val CHANNEL_ID = "1"// The id of the channel.
        val name = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)// The user-visible name of the channel.
        val mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
        val notificationIntent = Intent(context, GreenHCMActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle)



        val intent = Intent()
        val manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
        when(manufacturer) {
            "xiaomi" ->
                intent.component =
                    ComponentName(
                        "com.miui.securitycenter",
                        "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"
                    )
            "oppo" ->
                intent.component =
                    ComponentName(
                        "com.coloros.safecenter",
                        "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"
                    )
            "vivo" ->
                intent.component =
                    ComponentName(
                        "com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                        "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"
                    )
        }

        val list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
        )
        if (list.size > 0) {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }






        //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP )
        //val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
          // context,
            //1,
            //notificationIntent,
            //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        //)

        val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            1,
            notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )



        val mNotificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        //mNotificationManager.cancel(2);
        //mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
        {

            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                name,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,


                )



            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
           //mNotificationManager.cancel(1)
            mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 300, 300)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Selamat Sore Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi")
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()

                        // Provide the bitmap to be used as the payload for the BigPicture notification.
                        .bigPicture(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                context.resources,
                                R.drawable.absence2_2
                            )
                        )

                        // Override the large icon when the big notification is shown.
                        .bigLargeIcon(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                context.resources,
                                R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round
                            )
                        )


                    // Overrides ContentTitle in the big form of the template.
                    //.setBigContentTitle("Selamat Sore Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi ")


                    // Set the first line of text after the detail section in the big form of the template.
                    //.setSummaryText("")

                )

        }
        else
        {
            mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                //.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)

                    //lollipop, marshmallow, nougat
                .setContentTitle("Selamat Sore Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi")
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()

                        // Provide the bitmap to be used as the payload for the BigPicture notification.
                        .bigPicture(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                context.resources,
                                R.drawable.absence2_2
                            )
                        )


                        .setSummaryText("Mohon melakukan absensi sore ini,Terima kasih")
                        // Override the large icon when the big notification is shown.
                        .bigLargeIcon(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                context.resources,
                                R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round
                            )
                        )
                )




        }
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        mBuilder.setContentText("Mohon melakukan absensi sore ini,Terima kasih")
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        val note = mBuilder.build()
        //mBuilder.setContentText("Yth Kepada Seluruh Karyawan dimohon untuk melakukan absensi di pagi ini,Terima Kasih")

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build())
        //mNotificationManager.cancel(1)




    }


}
```

below inside oncreate will call 2 different times:

```
    //notif4 16.00 evening
    val _intent2 = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver2::class.java)
    val pendingIntent2  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, _intent2, 0)
    val alarmManager2 = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    //alarmManager2.cancel(pendingIntent2)
    //val calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance()
    val calendar2 = getInstance()
    //calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())
    calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16)
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18)
    calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    //calendar2.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
    alarmManager2.setInexactRepeating( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2 )



//notif3 07:00 morning
        val _intent = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, _intent, 0)
        val alarmManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
        val calendar = getInstance()
        //calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        //calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent )
```

How To Resolve This?  Hello I am nebie developer kotlin, I want to show push notification in kotlin at 7 AM & 16PM everyday, in here i make 2 broadcast receiver & 2 declare time inside oncreate, but sometimes push notification not show, i dont know if receiver blocked by miui saver, because sometimes show but wrong times.... I need more  help to resolve , thank you very much.....

Comment: AlaramManager not working after kill app following devices : OPPO,VIVO,MI or some chines phones Base on OS

Comment: can u give me solution for this sir? i am feel confuse now

Comment: before kill push notification can not show too and sometimes push notification show at wrong time :( example : set 7 AM but push notification show 05:30 AM :(

Comment: so sorry but not any solution in alaram manager send push notification using firebase this problam detect only chines mobile and OS

Comment: i am not use a firebase sir, only local in mainactivity

Comment: val calendar = getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)   alarmManager.setInexactRepeating( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent )

Comment: so you can download any alaram application and check alaram is working in MI UI or not after kill application

Comment: not showing in correct time,above my code, am i wrong ? :(

Comment: T_T my code error or wrong sir in above?

Comment: you first check other device like samsung or non chines mobile and confirm working or not

Comment: i dont have samsung sir :( only xiaomi